# Solving $C\cos(\sqrt\lambda\theta)+D\sin(\sqrt\lambda\theta)=C\cos(\sqrt\lambda(\theta+2m\pi)) + D\sin(\sqrt\lambda (\theta + 2m\pi))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, periodic-functions, multivalued-functions

> I want to solve
> $$C\cos(\sqrt\lambda \theta) + D\sin(\sqrt\lambda \theta) = C\cos(\sqrt\lambda (\theta + 2m\pi)) + D\sin(\sqrt\lambda (\theta + 2m\pi))$$
> The solution must be valid for all $\theta$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and all $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, but $C$, $D$, and $\lambda$ are to be determined and can be in $\mathbb{C}$.

The solutions I've found by guessing are $(C\ $arbitrary$, D\ $arbitrary$, \lambda = n^2)$, where $n$ is any integer, and $(C = 0, D = 0, \lambda\ $arbitrary$)$.

Is there some algebra I can do to show that these are the only solutions, or find the rest of the solutions to this equation?

Comment: Why do you express your equation with $\sqrt{\lambda}$ throughout?  You could have used alternate equally overly complex forms such as $\sqrt[17]{\lambda^{3/2}}$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It's just an artifact of the broader problem I am solving.  It didn't seem worth making a substitution and adding another variable to the mix just to remove the radical.

Comment: You should try to make the problem as simple as possible for solvers.  YOU can take their solution and add back in the complexity.  For instance solvers had to worry about $\lambda<0$ in your (poor) presentation.  Waste of time.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Shouldn't negative values of $\lambda$ be considered?  I don't think there's any prima facie constraint that $\sqrt{\lambda}$ be real.  Maybe it ends up always being real after one does the algebra though, not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_{C,D,\lambda}(\theta)
 = C\cos(\sqrt\lambda \theta) + D\sin(\sqrt\lambda \theta).$
Your want the values of the parameters $C,$ $D,$ and $\lambda$ such that

$$ f_{C,D,\lambda}(\theta) = f_{C,D,\lambda}(\theta + 2m\pi) $$

for all $\theta \in \mathbb R$ and all $m \in \mathbb Z.$
In other words, $f_{C,D,\lambda}$ must either be constant or must be non-constant with period $2\pi$ (implying a minimal period that divides $2\pi$).

You found the constant versions of $f_{C,D,\lambda},$ which require either $C=D=0$
or $\lambda = 0.$

For non-constant $f_{C,D,\lambda},$ note that $f_{C,D,\lambda}$ is sinusoidal
with period $2\pi/\sqrt\lambda.$
Hence $2\pi/\sqrt\lambda$ must divide $2\pi,$
hence $\sqrt\lambda$ must be a non-zero integer.
You found those solutions too.

Even if we allow $C,$ $D,$ $\lambda,$ and/or $\theta$ to be complex, $f_{C,D,\lambda}$ is still a single-valued function that is either constant or has period $2\pi/\sqrt\lambda.$
We can write
$$
f_{C,D,\lambda}(\theta) =
\frac12(C-iD)e^{i\sqrt\lambda \theta}
 + \frac12(C+iD)e^{-i\sqrt\lambda \theta}.
$$
For non-constant $f_{C,D,\lambda}$, therefore,
$2\pi/\sqrt\lambda$ must still divide $2\pi$ evenly,
hence $\sqrt\lambda$ must still be a non-zero integer,
and $\lambda$ must still be the square of a non-zero integer,
which gives a set of solutions that you already found.

As far as I can see there are no other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$ and  $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$. When you substitute this into your expression, on the left-hand side, you would get $ C(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}\theta} + e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}\theta}}{2}) + D(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}\theta} - e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}\theta}}{2i})$. On the right-hand side, you would end up with

$C(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}\theta} e^{2\pi mi\sqrt{\lambda}} + e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}\theta}e^{2\pi mi\sqrt{\lambda}}}{2}) + D(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}\theta}e^{2\pi mi\sqrt{\lambda}} - e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}\theta}e^{2\pi mi\sqrt{\lambda}}}{2i})$. Notice how the right-hand-side is similar to the left-hand side, except of the $e^{2\pi mi\sqrt{\lambda}}$ term. If we set this equal to 1 and solve for $\lambda$, we would see that $\sqrt{\lambda}$ would have to be an integer and therefore making $\lambda = n^2$

This explains the one solution for any C or D value. If you want to find any arbitrary C or D value, I would start by using Euler's formula to turn $C\cos{\sqrt{\lambda}\theta} + D\sin{\sqrt{\lambda}\theta}$ into one function,  and to do the same with the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

If $C=D=0$, then *every* $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ is a solution, since the equation is just $0=0$.

If $D=iC\not=0$, we can divide by $C$ and the equation becomes

$$e^{i\sqrt\lambda\theta}=e^{i\sqrt\lambda(\theta+2m\pi)}$$

the solutions to which must satisfy $\sqrt\lambda\theta=\sqrt\lambda(\theta+2m\pi)+2n\pi$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, which means we must have $\sqrt\lambda m\in\mathbb{Z}$. This holds for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\lambda$ is a square integer.

If $D\not=iC$, then, choosing $\phi\in\mathbb{C}$ so that $\cos\phi=C/\sqrt{C^2+D^2}$ and $-\sin\phi=D/\sqrt{C^2+D^2}$, the equation becomes

$$\cos(\phi+\sqrt\lambda\theta)=\cos(\phi+\sqrt\lambda(\theta+2m\pi))$$

so we must have

$$\phi+\sqrt\lambda\theta=\pm(\phi+\sqrt\lambda(\theta+2m\pi))+2n\pi$$

for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. And once again, the only way to have this hold for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ is for $\lambda$ to be a sqare integer (in which case the solution with the plus sign is satisfied).